# get Service_Name from the tns file using VBA

Tags: ms-access, oracle11g, vba

is there any way to pull the Service_Name from the TNS file using VBA? since anyone can name their TNS entries anything they want - my pass-through queries won't work on their computers.

if there's a way to setup the queries by using TNS entry itself instead of the SERVICE_NAME - that'd work too. i just want to make sure my database is not computer specific in any way.

for example, here's my DSN-less connection string

> [ODBC] DRIVER={Oracle in Oracle1}
>   UID=username
>   Pwd=password
>   DBQ=myTNSEntryName.ourcompany.com
>   Trusted_Connection=Yes
>   server= 
>   (DESCRIPTION= 
>       (ADDRESS= 
>         (PROTOCOL=TCP)
>         (HOST=ourhost.ourcompany.com) 
>         (PORT=9999) 
>       )
>       (CONNECT_DATA= 
>         (SERVICE_NAME=myTNSEntryName.ourcompany.com)
>        )   )

and here's my TNS entry

> myTNSEntryName.ourcompany.COM=
>   (DESCRIPTION=
>       (ADDRESS=
>         (PROTOCOL=TCP)
>         (HOST=ourhost.ourcompany.com)
>         (PORT=9999)
>       )
>       (CONNECT_DATA=
>         (SERVER=dedicated)
>         (SERVICE_NAME=ourdatabasename.ourcompany.com)
>       )   )

in the TNS file the SERVICE_NAME is ourdatabasename, but since i named the TNS entry myTNSEntryName - now using report.ourcompany.com as the SERVICE_NAME doesn't work.

thank you

EDIT: to clarify a little, basically i'm looking for a way to set up a DSN'less connection string that i can then use in the ODBC CONNECT STR line in the PROPERTIES of a MS Access Pass-Through query AND in the Docmd.TransferDatabase.

OR, find a way to read the user's TNS Entry name (not the database name, but whatever they choose to name their entires)

Answer (score 0):

The `DBQ` parameter is the TNS name that you want to use.  The Oracle ODBC driver does not use the `SERVER` or `TRUSTED_CONNECTION` parameters.  Microsoft's ODBC Driver for Oracle uses the `SERVER` parameter.  I'm not sure what, if any, driver might use the `trusted_connection` parameter or what that might do in an Oracle context.  Both of those should be removed.

Of course, the name of the Oracle ODBC driver may well be different on different machines since it contains the name of the Oracle Home and users are free to set that when they install the Oracle client.  If you want that to work on arbitrary machines, you'd need to interrogate the ODBC Driver Manager (using the `SQLDrivers` function) or you'd need to query the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers`

Comment: lol you caught the Oracle in Oracle1 part. Yes, i already got that part done, i'm querying to see which driver they're using. But the problem is that DBQ needs the TNS entry name which can be anything a user wants. so i was trying to find a way to either get the name of their TNS entry or find a way to setup the connection string so that it doesn't use the TNS Name, so that it uses the DatabaseName instead (which will always be the same).  Did i miunderstand your reply? and thank you, of course